# PHP session data from form not being passed and/or not printing to screen

Tags: php, html, forms, raspberry-pi

I am playing around with using my Raspberry Pi 3 as a web server.

I would like to learn more about processing user input through forms.

I have two files in `/var/www/html`, viz. `form.html` and `form.php`:

`form.html`:

```
<form action="form.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="varname"/>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit!" />
</form>

<?php

    session_start();

    if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) { 
    $_SESSION['varname'] = $_POST['varname'];
    }
?>
```

`form.php`:

```
<?php

    session_start();

    $var_value = htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['varname']);

    echo $var_value;

?>
```

When I click Submit! on `form.html` the browser takes me to `form.php` which displays a blank page.

Naturally, I would like it to print `$var_value` to the screen.

Is there problem in my code, or could it be some other server-side issue?

Comment: It's already in the first line of the PHP code blocks on both pages; should it be at the start of the entire document?

Comment: Does your server configuration allows execution of PHP code in `*.html` files? Try to change `*.html` file to `*.php` and try the result.

Comment: change your file name from form.html to form.php

Comment: PHP code does not run in a file with the `.html` extention by default. So the code in `form.html` will not run. **Also** PHP code runs before the page is thrown, so the PHP code in the `form.html` would not work, even if it was run, as `varname` does not exist, untill you submit that page to the `form.php` script

Comment: And `session_start()` should be the very first in the file otherwise headers will be sent with the content what will not start the session as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your form.html extension to form.php,

And you may use the below code to achieve your work.

**Form.php** // Single page

```
<?php
session_start(); // Should be in first Line
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) { 
    $_SESSION['varname'] = $_POST['varname'];
    $var_value = htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['varname']);
    echo $var_value;
    }
?>
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="varname"/>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit!" />
</form>
?>
```

**Otherwise:** // Multiple Page

**form.php**

```
<form action="some_form.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="varname"/>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit!" />
</form>
```

**some_form.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) { 
    $_SESSION['varname'] = $_POST['varname'];
    $var_value = htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['varname']);
    echo $var_value;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you. I now have two pages, the one is `html` and the other is `php`. The `html` file does not contain `session_start();`. Everything works perfectly now.